# Finding $\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{n\times 2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In one of my assignments, I have to prove the sum of the sequence converges.

$$\sum_{1}^N \frac{1}{n2^n}$$

If I'm not mistaken, that can be easily done by using a bounding sequence $\{b_n\}_0^N = \frac{1}{2^n} $, which also converges and is greater for all n.

However, I got curious at how to solve such a sequence. I couldn't find this problem anywhere. I tried to put it into the WolframAlpha and received an answer $ \log(2) $ using a "Lerch transcendent" (generalization of Hurwitz Zeta function as I've read on Wolfram) which I'm not familiar with.

I wanted to ask if there is any easier way to solve this sum. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 4):

Well, given that:
$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}x^n,\ |x|<1$$
pluging $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ into this equation can solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n.$$Then$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}.$$Since $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=-\log|1-x|$ and thefore$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n2^n}=f\left(\frac12\right)=-\log\left(\frac12\right)=\log2.$$